# ZMQ c# binding HWM not working

Tags: zeromq

HWM does not seem to work in clrzmq 2.2.5. 
Here's my code

```
    private static ulong hwm = 50;
    static void testMQ()
    {

        var _Context = new Context(1);

        var pubSock = _Context.Socket(SocketType.PUB); 
        pubSock.HWM = hwm;  
        pubSock.Bind("tcp://*:9999");

        new Thread(testSub).Start(); 
        Thread.Sleep(1000); // client connect

        int i = 0;
        while (true)
        {
            pubSock.Send(i.ToString(), Encoding.ASCII);
            Debug.WriteLine(pubSock.Backlog + "/" + i++);
        }
    }

    static void testSub()
    {
        var _ZmqCtx = new Context(1);

        var subSock = _ZmqCtx.Socket(SocketType.SUB);
        subSock.HWM = 500;
        subSock.Identity = new ASCIIEncoding().GetBytes("bla");
        subSock.Connect("tcp://127.0.0.1:9999");

        Debug.WriteLine("connected");
        subSock.Subscribe("", Encoding.ASCII);
        while (true)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("r:" + subSock.Recv(Encoding.ASCII));
            Thread.Sleep(10);
        }
    }
```

Output:

```
'quickies.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)):      
Loaded 'B:\sdev\MSenseWS\GoogleImporter\bin\Debug\clrzmq.dll', Symbols loaded.
connected
r:0
100/0
100/1
100/2 
[...]
100/13
r:1
100/14
[...] 
100/2988
100/2989
100/2990
100/2991
100/2992
100/2993
100/2994
100/2995
100/2996
r:179
100/2997
100/2998
```

Expected behavior: pubSock.Send blocks after 500 messages are queued. 
Experienced behavior: pubSock.Sends does not block and sends forever until out of memory exception vom native code (clrzmq.dll) is thrown.

Also: Why is backlog always 100?

Thanks for your insights,
Armin

Edit: push/poll sockets achieve the same result

#
#

Resolution: 
- The error was on my side, as i was expecting that the HWM is the number of outstanding messages that the clinet(s) have not commited (received). While in fact HWM is the number of messages that are buffered and queued for sending over the network.

- In my case i had a client that can not process messages fast enough and so buffer space was allocated until out of memory.
- To solve this problem i found out that setting HWM and SWAP on the client socket solves my problem, as messages are queued to a large swap file by zmq and are successively precessed by the application.

Comment: Is your client connecting in this case? Since I don't see the "connected" you're sending to debug log in your output.

Comment: yes it is connecting, i have added the first few lines to the output of the post...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, so I'm guessing you have the subscriber thread sleep, but that doesn't mean the underlying ZMQ socket threads also sleep. Therefore the subscriber will continue to take messages off the publisher queue. In other words, using `Thread.Sleep()` is probably not a good enough way to simulate limited network connectivity or other issues you expect to cause running into the HWM.

Comment: Thanks. This is quite diffrent from many other mq frameworks. I have updated the post...